# Usb drive showing corrupted files after moving to a folder in same directory

Tags: partitioning, usb, permissions, mount

I was trying to create a zipped folder of all folders in my USB stick. For that I created a folder named 'All' inside the USB folder (mounted under `/dev/sdb1/`) and used this command:
`mv !(All) ./All/`. It is supposed to move all other folders to All except the folder All itself. But it seemingly corrupted the file system.When I try to go inside that all folder it is showing this error message: `Error while getting information for the file /media/usb_stick/folder2, input/output error`. When I go inside the All folder from terminal and list the contents, it is showing such output:

```
d????????? ? ?       ?           ?            ?  folder1
d????????? ? ?       ?           ?            ? 'folder 2'
d????????? ? ?       ?           ?            ?  folder3
d????????? ? ?       ?           ?            ?  folder4
```

Somehow the partition is corrupted. Can someone tell me how to fix this?
I used `sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/sdb1/`, it is showing the following error: `fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24); open: Not a directory`

Comment: those ???? are just a result of you not having execute permissions on the folder. do `chmod +x` on the folder and see if anything changes, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697554/is-this-an-expected-directory-under-run-user-1000/697557#697557)

Comment: @Esther it says `chmod: changing permissions of 'All': Read-only file system`